# App Building on Simulator not on Device: XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, sup

I am developing a SUP based iOS application. I went a way through running the application on simulator, and never tested it on device. There is a folder Library, this is a static library that supports debugging and running application on simulator as well as on device. I have mentioned its absolute path in "Library Search Path" as:

`$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/${BUILD_STYLE}-${PLATFORM_NAME}` with recursive.

When I build my application with simulator, it works fine. But when I run it with device it throws some warning and 68 similar errors given below.

> ld: warning: ignoring file Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libAfariaSLL.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (armv7s): Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libAfariaSLL.a ld: warning:
>   ignoring file Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libclientrt.a, file was built
>   for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libclientrt.a ld: warning: ignoring file
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libDatavault.a, file was built for archive
>   which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libDatavault.a ld: warning: ignoring file
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libMo.a, file was built for archive which is
>   not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libMo.a ld: warning: ignoring file
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libsupcore.a, file was built for archive
>   which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libsupcore.a ld: warning: ignoring file
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libSUPObj.a, file was built for archive which
>   is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libSUPObj.a ld: warning: ignoring file
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libsupUltralite.a, file was built for archive
>   which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libsupUltralite.a ld: warning: ignoring file
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libMO.a, file was built for archive which is
>   not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
>   Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/libMO.a Undefined symbols for architecture
>   armv7s:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDataType", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerActivityMetaData.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerChangeLogImplMetaData.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerChangeLogKeyMetaData.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerEmployeeCraftMetaData.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerEmployeeMetaData.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerEmployeeUserMetaData.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerEquipmentMetaData.o
>         ...   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDatabaseMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerWorkPlannerDBMetaData in WorkPlannerWorkPlannerDBMetaData.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractStructure", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerChangeLogKey in WorkPlannerChangeLogKey.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerKeyGeneratorPK in WorkPlannerKeyGeneratorPK.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerKeyPackageName in WorkPlannerKeyPackageName.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerLocalActivityEmployeeAssociationKey in WorkPlannerLocalActivityEmployeeAssociationKey.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerLocalActivityEquipmentAssociationKey in WorkPlannerLocalActivityEquipmentAssociationKey.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerLocalKeyGeneratorPK in WorkPlannerLocalKeyGeneratorPK.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerLocalPlanDetailKey in WorkPlannerLocalPlanDetailKey.o
>         ...   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPKeyGenerator", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerKeyGenerator.o
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_WorkPlannerKeyGenerator in WorkPlannerKeyGenerator.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDefaultCallbackHandler",
>   referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_CallbackHandler in CallbackHandler.o   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPKeyGenerator", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_WorkPlannerKeyGenerator in WorkPlannerKeyGenerator.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPClassDelegate",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerChangeLogKey.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerKeyGeneratorPK.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerKeyPackageName.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerLocalActivityEmployeeAssociationKey.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerLocalActivityEquipmentAssociationKey.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerLocalKeyGeneratorPK.o
>         objc-class-ref in WorkPlannerLocalPlanDetailKey.o

Please help in understanding what wrong is happening with my build setting or schema.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target is SUP 2.1.3 on iPad3/iOS6 built with XCode 4.5 you should be able to do it without problems.

I'm developing an app with exactly the same specifics and I have no problem running it both with the Simulator and the device itself.

You should be able to fix it just by changing the architecture of the project from *Standard* to *armv7* (add it using *Other...* if you don't see the option) and it will run on the iPad3.

[image: XCode]

Comment: I am using exactly the same combination that you have provided above. But what is the command instead of `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`

Comment: Select 'Other...' -> + sign -> add 'armv7'

Comment: Beware of one thing, tho: I'm not sure the app will run on an iPad4, since that one should be armv7s based. I haven't had a chance to test mine on the new device.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing on iPhone 5 or iPod 5 which has armv7s architecture([what-is-armv7s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569339/what-is-armv7s)) but your library is not build with support for armv7s. YOu need to get your library build for armv7s architecture as well to support for new devices.

Comment: Try running on iPhone(Retina 4-inch) simulator, you will get same errors.

Comment: when I ran this application on iPad simulator 6.0..it's working!! not on iPad 3 with iOS 6??

Comment: You will get these errors only on iPhone 5 & iPhone(Retina 4-inch) simulator. Other devices or simulators don't have A6 processor. And armv7s is for A6 processor.

Comment: Sorry. iPad 3 also has A6 processor, that's why it's not working on it.

Comment: I also worked with iPad 2 with iOS 6 installed and worked with iPad 1 with iOS 5...behave same way!!

Comment: and simulator in xcode comes, depending on iOS version. Not specific to hardware.