# Build 1.0.0 does not contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information, see the iTunes Connect Developer Guide

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

```
Build 1.0.0 does not contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information, see the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.
```

I uploaded my App to the iTunes Connect a couple of days ago with the initial version number 1.0.0 and it's under "Waiting For Review" status. I explored this warning message under the "Prerelease" section today. Does anyone seen this before? Will apple reject my App based on this warning? And how do I fix this issue please?

Comment: This same basic question was just asked a few minutes before yours - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756669/app-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement

Comment: yep, I guess it relates to the new iTunes connect updates which happened a few days ago. Never seen this before.

Comment: I think you're OK. I think any build that gets submitted ends up there, and prerelease versions can't use the same profile/entitlements so it shows up as failed?  I'm actually trying to upload a prerelease with a ad-hock distribution, but I have no idea what this error means, and how I fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regenerate you iOS Provisioning Profiles (Distribution), then rebuild your binary with the new provisioning profile file and resubmit. It's gonna work.

Comment: Is it has to be fixed in order to pass the app review?

Comment: Actually you can still choose the uploaded build and submit for review. The status will be changed to "waiting for review". The new itunes connect is buggy.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and resolved it by recreate appstore provisioning (old provisioning made this error)

Comment: Have you submitted new version on iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

**i face this problem and it was because missing entitlement .
although i dont use in-app purchase nor game center capabilites "entitlement" in my app but it declared in APP ID when you create it in developer portal and enabled by default as you see below image** 
[image: App ID Services from developer account]

**So the solution is to provide the entitlement in your plist**
**1) please turn on in-app purchase & game Center capabilities then turn it of again , this will add the missing entitlement** AS Follow
[image: project capabilities from xcode]

Comment: Do I need to re-upload my App to iTunes Connect after doing this (which will remove my App from the waiting queue)?

Comment: And also, does apple gonna reject my app if I don't fix this warning?

Comment: if the triangle still appear you will not be able to enter apple review proccess .
i was upload a build and i use it , then the app enter waiting for review status but after 1 day it was binary rejected

Comment: @nzkevinCan you pls tell me.. if i am getting the same warning App “does not contain the correct beta entitlement” in iTunes Connect, So should i need to reupload my new binary , apple can reject my app?

Comment: yes you should ,
did you submit your app to review , i think no . you have to choose the version you want to submit the press submit for review .