# Regenerating the provisioning profile does not solve missing entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, beta-testing

I am sure this question has been asked before, specially -

[Build 1.0.0 does not contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information, see the iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756718/build-1-0-0-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement-for-more-information)

and

[App "does not contain the correct beta entitlement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756669/app-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement)

Also apple suggests the same work to do - recreate the distribution profiles.

As I was encountering this problem, I went through all these steps.

So, I removed old profiles, regenerated them and reloaded them in xcode, restarted xcode. Then I cleaned and archived again, I made sure the the archived binary is using the new profile and checked that the "beta-reports-active" is set to 1 (true)

But, still no luck and I keep getting the same error message. After the binary is uploaded it keep saying "To use TestFlight Beta Testing, this build must contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information, see the FAQ."

That's why it's going to be frustrating and posting this question in a hope if there is a secondary reason?

Comment: Do you have a rekord of the app in itunesconnect.apple.com?

Comment: @IbrahimYildirim Yes. Previous version is already approved and live in iTunes. I added a new version and trying to upload for beta testing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to remove the TestFlight SDK (version 3.0) which was included in my project from older versions.

Now the error is gone.