# itunes connect - not contain the correct beta entitlement

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, marmalade

I read that:
[App "does not contain the correct beta entitlement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756669/app-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement)

1. I recreate production provisioning profile
2. I checking info.plist

Still the same bug. Last answer from topic above is recreate xcode entitlement "So the solution is to provide the entitlement in your plist 1) please turn on in-app purchase & game Center capabilities then turn it of again , this will add the missing entitlement AS Follow "

can you answer what .plist is generate (not info.plist?) and what data is changed after it (what section). Because I manualy edit info.plist (Marmalade SDK application), I can't edit entitlements from XCode.

Answer (score 2):

The new itunes connect is buggy. Try:

1. Regenerate you iOS Provisioning Profiles (Distribution), then rebuild your binary with the new provisioning profile file and resubmit.
2. Actually you can still choose the uploaded build and submit for review. The status will be changed to "waiting for review".