# The correct beta entitlement for TestFlight Beta Testing in iTunesConnect with FlashBuilder

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-builder, app-store-connect, testflight

I develop games on ActionScript with FlashBuilder. I want to use TestFlight Beta Testing in iTuneConnect. But the builds that I compile with FlashBuilder don't contain the correct entitlement. **I've generated new provisioning file, downloaded it and compiled my app with it**. I use Adobe AIR SDK 15.0.0.295.

How can I generate the correct entitlement?

Olga

Comment: You don't generate them yourself, they have to be generated for you from your apple development account.

Comment: @BotMaster That's what I mean - I've generated new provisioning file in apple development account, downloaded it and created the release build using it. It didn't help. I've checked the provisioning file - it contains the right parameter:         <key>beta-reports-active</key>
        <true/>

Comment: @BotMaster Did you succeed to use the TestFlight Beta testing?

Answer (score 2):

Updating to [Adobe AIR SDK & Compiler (version 15.0.0.302)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) and adding the following code to the **-app.xml** file fixes this problem.

```
<Entitlements>
<![CDATA[ <key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
<key>beta-reports-active</key>
<true/> ]]>
</Entitlements>
```

Found this code here: [Enabling TestFlight testing in iTunes Connect for Adobe AIR apps](http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/99200413877/enabling-testflight-testing-in-itunes-connect-for-adobe)

Answer (score 1):

This particular answer on a different thread helped me the most.
You WILL have to generate a new distribution profile if you created one before the launch of TestFlight.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221904/870274

"Yes, you need to recreate provisioning profile and one more important thing is that you need to provision your app with App Store distribution provisioning profile.

You can also convert .mobileprovision file to .xml with that command to see if there really is a beta-reports-active key in your entitlements.

```
security cms -D -i YourProfile.mobileprovision > YourProfile.xml
```

Comment: I've checked the xml file and found:

'<key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>

    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>'