# What does the warning / exclamation mark next to prerelease builds mean?

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I am trying the new prerelease feature for Mac on iTunes Connect.
I uploaded my build and it appears in the prerelease section of my app. However there is a small warning sign next to it and i cannot release the build to any testers or edit the test meta data.
[image: warning signs in iTunes Connect]

I tried the following:

- upload the app as I would for a App Store release
- add devices to team provisioning profile and upload with that provisioning profile

What does the warning mean?
Do I have to upload the build built with the team provisioning profile or with the distribution profile?
Can I later update the provisioning profile as I could on TestFlight or do I need to re-upload whenever I add a device?

---

**Update:**

I found the following sentence in the iTunesConnect [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html):

> TestFlight beta testing in iTunes Connect is available only for iOS apps

I don't understand why beta testing is offered in the GUI of Mac apps in iTunesConnect if it is not supported.
Has anyone successfully deployed Mac beta apps, yet, or is that in deed not possible?

Comment: Did you try clicking on the warning icon?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. The icon is not clickable. I can click the build number but there is no valuable info behind it (at least no error message), just techinical details of the build (entitlements etc.) and the test instructions which I cannot edit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the new beta entitlement. Describing a little bit for others also:

After Archiving, Export the corresponding build using **Save for IOS App Store Deployment** method. Without this option `beta-reports-active = 1` will not be added for the binary. This is the reason for warning on itunesconnect.

If the warning continues after the **Save for IOS App Store Deployment** selection then you should check if the provisioning profile was created/regenerated recently. Because before some months ago this `beta-reports-active` flag was not included from the developer site.

The following link will be helpful [correct beta entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756669/app-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement).

Comment: I am having the problem with a Mac app. I updated the question as it might be that Mac apps are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever figure out how to find out why this is there?  I was getting this about 1 month ago and through trail and error found that it was because I had a WatchKit extension in my project.  This warning just returned for me today with Xcode 6.2, but I can't figure out what is causing it.  I already removed my WatchKit extension from this build.

**Edit**

I figured out what was going on for me.  I accidentally didn't get everything for my Watch App targets removed from my project.  Once I removed them, this warning in ITC went away.

Comment: so what did you removed ... for you apple watch ?