# Appstore Add Build Warning

Tags: ios, warnings, entitlements

I am getting a warning icon while trying to submit the app to App Store. I am using XCode 6.4 to submit the app directly to the app store from Organizer itself, I usually do like that only.

[image: Add Build]

On clicking the warning icon, I am unable to see any reasons described. I tried with all the browsers for this.

I saw the below links also where they talk about `beta-reports-active = 1` entitlement and I have made sure that it is present and also I am not using  `watch kit`. Below is the snapshot of entitlements

[image: Binary and entitlements]

[Build warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664036/what-does-the-warning-exclamation-mark-next-to-prerelease-builds-mean)

[Build upload warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756669/app-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement)

So not sure what is the issue, the only thing that I did recently is that, since our certificate was expiring soon, I did a reset of the certificate using Xcode 7 (since it was easy to do it with Xcode 7). This ended up in having a profile automatically created by Xcode, now when I archive and try to submit, Xcode is picking this XC: profile.

Just wanted to know, if it is okay to submit even with this warning. Need to push a patch fix soon. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of refresh of the screen the Warning went off, then in the next refresh, warning came back.Also I started seeing radio button names eg:`"Manually release this version"` as `ITC.Manuall.....`. just crazy!!

Looked like something weird with the iTunes Connect site. In the next refresh where I got with no warning, I went ahead and submitted uh!!!...I couldn't run around with no clue :)

**UPDATE: THE APP GOT APPROVED...HOOF!!!**