# iOS: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements

Tags: ios, braintree, applepay

I am working on Apple Pay integration using Braintree API, I did integrate successfully, but apple pay was not integrated. When I created `Archive`, it gave me this warning

> none of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified
>   entitlements beta-reports-active, com.apple.developer.in-app-payments

Comment: I work at Braintree. If you have an urgent problem, please [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) by phone or email.

Comment: Are you trying to perform enterprise distribution? What does your provisioning profile look like? Note that the Apple Pay entitlement is not compatible with enterprise distribution.

Comment: If you're not doing enterprise distribution: can you confirm that Apple Pay has been enabled for your App ID? (This can be confirmed in Xcode > Project > Capabilities). You can also try deleting and recreating the provisioning profile -- it may need to be regenerated to add the new entitlements.

Comment: @RichardShin I did enable Apple Pay from capabilities, and added that merchant.com.myorg.myapplication as merchant id , which i created on apple developer portal.

Comment: @magid Have you tried recreating the provisioning profile?

Comment: yes i did make new pp

Comment: Hi @magid, you may also need to regenerate your distribution cert before regenerating your provisioning profile. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25757196/766491).

Comment: @magid - It sounds like you have integrated the Braintree/Apple Pay code without being interested in Apple Pay. Are you trying to figure out how to implement Apple Pay, or how to submit to the app store with Braintree _without_ Apple Pay?

Comment: I am sorry, I am really busy now a days. I integrated payments without Apple Pay. and uploaded other cards and Paypal.
Once they are approved. I'll do later this Apple Pay in my apps later, as it is really messy, No tutorials. Just followed written docs, thats it..

Comment: I'll appreciate if Apple Pay Method is defined anywhere . not on Braintree side, but on Apple side. I was able to create entitlements..

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Braintree account => Settings => Procesing => Apple Pay => Certificates => Download a certificate signing request (NOT the Download link on the right)