# Uploading new build to Testflight but keeping old build live (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm new to this, so please bear with me. I have an app live on the App store, developed in Xamarin. The current version is 1.0.3 and I want to keep it that way. I want to send a new build (i.e build 85) via Application loader  with the same version number (1.0.3).

I want to know:

1. Will it become live as soon as I send it or will I have the option to keep the previous build (i.e 84) live and not this one (i.e 85)? I want the previous build (84) to be live.
2. Can I upload a build that I got from Ad-Hoc > iPhone => myApp.ipa / currently I'm doing this only or should I generate an ipa from a different configuration like "Release" or  "App Store"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try uploading your build with the same version number as your current live build, Application Loader will give you an error message saying you need to create a new app version profile in iTunes Connect.

You should be able to upload an Ad-Hoc build to ITC. However, you may need to tweak your entitlements to enable beta testing via TestFlight:

[App "does not contain the correct beta entitlement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756669/app-does-not-contain-the-correct-beta-entitlement)