# iOS 8 GM - Can't Install IPA

Tags: ios, xcode

Yesterday I installed both iOS 8 GM on my development iPad and XCode 6 GM on my Mac. Most of my Apps keep workings fine but there is one that I can't install anymore. The same IPA that worked on iOS7 now just doesn't install. I tried both a webpage owned by me where is correctly placed the plist and other images and Diawi. Both ways lead to the same result: when "XXX wants to install APP on your iPad" pop-up and I click OK, nothings happens. Nothing.

There is someone who got through this on iOS 8?

Comment: I found a solution that works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app/27603438#27603438

Comment: @EvaMadrazo Hi! Thanks for the comment but even if that works, I can't force all the users of my App to do that procedure. I hope they will fix it directly from a release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Error message on device console:

```
<Warning>: LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID: my.company.testapp
```

Managed to solve with the help of this comment:

http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/26683-not-able-to-download-apps-ios8-beta-5-autoupdate-manually-etc#comment_34327687

that is in .plist renamed *bundle-identifier* to some random string.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by installing the official release of yesterday. I couldn't access the device console with iOS 8 GM.

Comment: I have rename the bundle id as com.comapanyname.qa1 but still get the issue when you reinstall it. so every time for reinstalling app from remote deployment server, we need to rename com.companyname.qa2.. qa3 .. so on. I think it is bug or Apple wants to force us to use testflight?