# iOS8 Enterprise app install issue

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

I have been looking into this issue for a long time now and have gone over many questions on here which have helped clear up somethings but I am now getting some new warnings and errors in the device logs and I am unable to decipher them.

Firstly I was getting the following:

```
<Warning>: LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID:
```

which wouldn't even kick the install off but I followed the steps in the following link: [iOS 8 - Can't Install Enterprise App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app) made some changes to the bundle identifier and the manifest file and it would try and kick off the download.

However I am now getting the following errors/warnings and I am unsure what is causing them:

```
<Notice>: 0x101dcc000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.bundle-name; Version=3.0, ShortVersion=(null)>  
<Error>: 0x198de7310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such process  
<Error>: 0x198de7310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory  
<Error>: 0x198de7310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory  
<Error>: 0x198de7310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory 
<Error>: 0x198de7310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory 
<Error>: 0x198de7310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory 
<Error>: 0x198de7310 Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
```

as well as:

```
<Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13cf84870> com.bundle-name(Placeholder) withPhase:3  
<Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.bundle-name.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x13e003120> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
```

and:

```
<Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
```

Any Help deciphering these and shedding some light would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I went back and checked iOS 7.1.1 and it was failing to installing there so I switched the manifest file iPA url back to being ftp:// and it worked on 7.1.1 again but iOS8 throws the following warning and fails to download the app:

```
<Notice>: Invalid URL scheme for background tasks: ftp. Valid schemes are http or https
```

but switching the IPA url over to HTTPS means the app doesn't download for both iOS 7.1.1 or iOS 8.1

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @marym-matthews I have managed to solve my problem see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and here is everything I did to get it working.

**Our setup + backstory:**

We have an AWS webserver with an HTTPS website running on it. Since iOS 7.1 our manifest (plist) is hosted on the server but the IPA was stored on an FTP and this worked fine throughout iOS 7. The introduction of iOS 8 meant the FTP could no longer be used for the IPA so we wanted to move it onto the webserver the same as the PLIST. Before doing this though we had other issues that were preventing the iPad from even trying to download because I was getting the following error message:

```
Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID: {bundle_id}
```

**The Fix:**

Firstly I followed the steps in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app) and made sure that both `full-size-image` and `display-image` exist in the manifest file.

I then made some other changes to the manifest file based on another answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app). These changes were to the `bundle-identifier` and `bundle-version`

In doing this my iOS 8 test iPad would pick up the install display the shadow icon but then fail to install, however the iOS 7 iPad would still install I saw the following message:

```
<Notice>: Invalid URL scheme for background tasks: ftp. Valid schemes are http or https
```

Which led me to move all the files onto the webserver, but then both iOS 7 and iOS 8 wouldn't install.

I originally thought one of the above errors / warnings might have been causing it to fail but couldn't seem to find an answer. After hours of searching and trying to fix I had an epiphany because when trying to view the IPA in a web browser I was getting a 404 and I remembered we had a similar issue when moving the PLIST file onto the server. To fix this I had to add the IPA MIME type on the IIS 7 server. As soon as I did this my 7 build of our app will download an install on both the iOS 7 and iOS 8 iPads. The correct MIME type for an `application/octet-stream`