# iOS 8.1 Can't install OTA Enterprise app - "Unable to download app"

Tags: deployment, ios-provisioning, xcode6.1, ios8.1, over-the-air

I know that my question is similar to this [iOS8 Enterprise app install issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506304/ios8-enterprise-app-install-issue)
However none of the answers helped me and I no one explained the crash log errors which I think hold the key for solving the real problem rather then trying to add another solution that might work.

What I tried so far:

- This is how my problem looks like :[iOS 8 - Can't Install Enterprise App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app) : none fixes or links helped
- Tried all from ground on - All new certificates/provisioning profiles...[iOS Enterprise OTA distribution Unable to Download Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375387/iphone-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time/15259206#15259206)
- Tried hotfixes, cleaning devices, restarts and vodoo stuff...[Enterprise App Update Distribution on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8)

Here are the logs:

```
iPad-itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.firmName.

iPad installd[34] <Notice>: 0x1ad5000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5715016884658519113.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 81)
```

PID 81 = app installation request

PID 31 = pid81 request a placeholder installation which should be done in the background by pid 31

```
iPad installd[34] <Notice>: 0x1ad5000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.firmName.AppyName; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=(null)>
```

Installation in progress...

```
iPad MobileStorageMounter[187] <Error>: 0x3cce29dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such process
iPad MobileStorageMounter[187] <Error>: 0x3cce29dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
iPad MobileStorageMounter[187] <Error>: 0x3cce29dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
iPad MobileStorageMounter[187] <Error>: 0x3cce29dc Device-O-Matic: iterate_ancestors IORegistryEntryGetParentIterator failed: No such file or directory
```

ERROR OCCURRED

The `MobileStorageMounter`sounds the error, it isn't cause of the ipad storage there is plenty space. PID 31 got killed therefore there is not process and it seems the placeholder got removed aswell thats why there is no such file or directory?

Here is the rest:

```
iPad installd[34] <Notice>: 0x1ad5000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.firmName.AppyName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FE556E7D-F0BF-4E83-8140-5A9BA7574E8A
iPad installd[34] <Notice>: 0x1ad5000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for com.firmName.AppyName at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D3564BA0-3940-40EB-926F-F1A04D5FA5BF

iPad installd[34] <Notice>: 0x1ad5000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.04s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.70s; Overall: 0.74s
iPad itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14d26cf0> com.firmName.AppyName (Placeholder) withPhase:3

iPad itunesstored[81] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.firmName.AppyName.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x14f94a40> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache

iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
iPad lockdownd[24] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token: 22
iPad lockdownd[24] <Error>: Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
iPad filecoordinationd[138] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.firmName.AppyName (bundle id (null), EF50B943-DC1D-493E-AAD3-DBAEA8F380D8)

iPad filecoordinationd[138] <Warning>: sandboxing denied subscription to progress on category com.firmName.AppyName (bundle id com.apple.iaptransportd, AC37404E-9FF1-474E-A2A3-F92E3E3EE0ED)
```

It seems that PID 81 completed with 0 of 100 and was removed. It seems that all failed at the placeholder creation?

The app works perfectly when build by Xcode 6.1.1 and plugged into any device. The also worked one time via Enterprise distribution and then never again (I downloaded and installed it, after which this was never possible). The app is always in the "Waiting..." state.

Any advice or idea is welcome. I really have no clue anymore or any idea. Is there another way beside OTA/Adhoc distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all combinations of answers and solutions for iOS 8.1. both on iPads and iPods with getting no step further. The solution that works is using apples testFlight.
I think that the old way is meant not to work so developers would slowly switch to testFlight.
I wasted two working days, hope this helps you rather then wasting time.

About testFlight: [testFlight apple page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/)

This simple tutorial lead me: [iOS8 testFlight tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)

UPDATE 1 (24.05.2015):

The enterprise distribution is working now for me.My colleague updated the SSL on the server twice. He updated some two keys that were used for SSL authentication since some certificates have been changed and updated. Also the distribution works on the following devices:

iPod (4th,8.2),iPhone 5S(8.3), iPad 2 (8.3), iPad 4(8.3).

However it doesn't work and doesn't give any error report (or error line) in Xcode - Window - Devices iPad 3 Console. I have been using successfully uploaded my app using Xcode 6.2+ IDE (currently 6.3.1.). In all cases no default plist file was added and I used the plist file from here : [Xcode 6 enterprise plist file example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910387/xcode-6-save-for-enterprise-deployment-does-not-create-plist-for-ipa-anymore)

Comment: Hi sir, I manage to download and install for all my devices (iPhone & iPad) but my customer can't. The message is the same. So that is really weird, let people download and install directly is what the enterprise account's important feature isn't it?

Comment: Hi @Alan. One possible solution could be the iOS version of your customer? On which one does it work for you and on which one doesn't it work on the customers device? Also I had some minor issues with iPad Airs. Check the version problem first.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the Same Issues.

Possible workaround is to rename ipa and plist. Then it worked for me.

But I got still no Clue Why this ist happening.

Comment: Did you distribute to iOS 7.1 and it worked (with the name changes)?

Comment: 7.1 and 8.1.1. Sending out a ticket to apple, just want to know why this is happening and working with rename..

Comment: Tried the rename, and didn't work for me on. So far I have tested it on a iphone 4 iOS 7.1

Comment: I was having this same issue with Books(epub), After renaming the plist it worked fine.

Comment: I was having this same issue with Books(epub), After renaming the plist it worked fine. Thanks, @user1847350

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems. It worked itself out by not setting any "team" or specific provision profile/code signing cert. for the build target in Xcode project file.

Step-by-step

- Team set to "None" (under General)
- iOS Developer/Distribution to Automatic under Code signing (Build Settings)
- Provisioning profile set to "None"

then Product -> Archive -> Distribute -> Save for Ad Hoc/Enterprise -> Choose your enterprise prov. profile -> save to disk -> install/distribute

Found [this site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html) regarding code sign errors

Comment: This solution didn't work for ENT OTA distribution on iphone 4 iOS 7.1. I will try it again with Identity - Team set To ENT_ACC and some other changes.

Comment: I doesn't work in any way with any configuration. The error is always the same can not download at this time.

Comment: Tried installation via adHoc Developer account , didn't work (ios 7.1.2 iphone 4). Same error. Installing the app on the device via cable works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same “Unable to download app” issue when trying to download an enterprise app to an iPad.

Something that worked for me was powering the iPad off and on again.

No idea why this worked but it did. Hope it helps someone!