# Use configuration profile to install app?

Tags: ios, apple-configurator

I'm trying to distribute my app through an Apple Configuration Profile, but I can't figure out how to get the app to get embedded into the profile. I know it's possible because of the [semi-jailbreak](http://www.semijb.com) process.How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should register as an enterprise developer in apple's developer membercenter.
You should have a website which support https protocol.

I guess this quest may help you.

[iOS 8 - Can't Install Enterprise App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't register for an enterprise developer. I also only have http://, not https://. Is there still a way?

Comment: http can be resolved by some other way. But if want others to install your app in safari, I think you must become an enterprise developer first, maybe there are some other way, but sorry, I have not found one.