# Unable to install enterprise app - This provisioning profile cannot be installed on this device

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I'm setting up Jenkins to build an enterprise version of an app in order to be distributed in our internal app store.

If I archive the app in Xcode and then download the built .ipa on the phone the app is installed without any issue; but when I use the .ipa generated with Jenkins with the same private key/certificate/provisioning profile, installation fails with the following error: "Unable to Download App - App name could not be installed at this time"

If I check the console in Xcode I can see some more details errors as "This provisioning profile cannot be installed on this device"

Here is part of the log

```
<Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=af11a784-f15d-4291-92a1-0e0c54fc4ee9; Version=13, ShortVersion=0.0.1>
<Notice>: attempt to install invalid profile: 0xe8008012
<Error>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstallableBundle _installEmbeddedProfileInBundle:]: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012 (This provisioning profile cannot be installed on this device.)
<Error>: 0x16e12f000 MIMachOUnhideArchsSavingOriginalHeader: Failed to open "/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.YMpQfe/extracted/Payload/appName.app/appName": No such file or directory
<Error>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:]: 696: Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.YMpQfe/extracted/Payload/appName.app/appName
<Error>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
<Error>: 0x16e247000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=14 "Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.YMpQfe/extracted/Payload/appName.app/appName" UserInfo={SourceFileLine=696, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.YMpQfe/extracted/Payload/appName.app/appName, FunctionName=-[MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:]}
<Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
```

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Apple's "Provisioning Hell"

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing with provisioning. Offending line `Failed to unhide archs` means that you're not compiling for given architecture (armv7 or arm64 depending on the device you install to).

Comment: I get the same error, but I'm compiling for ARMv7 + ARM64 and that should be OK. The error should mean something differently ...

Answer (score 0):

I had also different errors like

> Failed to unhide archs in executable file

as well as

> error MT0000: Unexpected error

or

> Error: error MT1006: Could not install the application

or

> AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe800801c

Now I got it running again after:

- Cleaning solution
- Deleting content of obj/bin folders
- Multiple restart of devices (Mac, iPad, PC, ...)

In general, I recommend to update you development/build environment and to also check your certificates.