# iPad with iOS 8 or 9 : Can't install enterprise app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have been trying to install an .ipa using itms-services to an iPad with iOS 9.1. However, it shows the "Install..app?" and "Unable to install.." pop-ups the same as asked in this question:

[iOS 8 - Can't Install Enterprise App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app)

The installation is successful in iPhone with iOS 9.1 (same version as iPad). I tried the installation in another iPad with iOS 8.1. I tried the suggested fixes in the accepted answer of the above mentioned question. Also, tried cleaning the Downloads folder using iExplorer. Still unable to download.

I'm able to install app using iTunes, so it's not a provisioning profile issue.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this stupid error can occur.  To be overly cautious, let's..

1) delete the app from your ipad

2) delete all of the related provisioning profiles from your ipad

3) in xcode make sure you are using the provisioning profile correctly associated with the enterprise account (bundle identifiers must match properly) .. also make sure the DEPLOYMENT TARGET is lower than the ios version on the ipad

4) in xcode -> product-> clean

5) xcode -> product-> archive

6) while its building, turn your ipad off then back on

7) upload the enterprise build

8) try to redownload and install it on the ipad

- there is a VERY VERY small chance that your wifi is corrupting the downloaded file, to check, see if you can get it to install on your iphone via wifi as well.
- connect the ipad to your computer via usb, while doing the install,  open up in xcode -> window -> devices, pick your ipad in the left column and hit the very tiny little square with an up arrow in it to show the console.. clear it before you open the app, then open the app and see what it says, this will give you more clues hopefully of whats going wrong