# iOS Enterprise: What should I change or keep the same so an updated app installs over the older version?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios-enterprise

I'm responsible for re-signing apps, which our vendors create, with our Enterprise cert and then distributing them internally. The last time we had an update to an existing app, users had to uninstall the old version before installing the new one otherwise they would have two identical looking apps on their home screen.

What do I need to change and/or keep the same in the manifest.plist file so future app updates overwrite the existing app? Do I need to do anything different with the Provisioning Profile?

In light of the [manifest cache bug in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app), will changing the bundle-identifier make what I want impossible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the app's bundle id the same. That's all that matters for the app to be treated as an update. If the bundle id changes then it gets installed as a new, separate app.

Comment: I'm not sure 100%, but you might want to add that not only the "bundle identifier" as it appears in Xcode (e.g, `com.myCompanyName.MyAppName`) needs to be the same, but also the prefix (e.g., `D2D4T4F87R`, seen in the Developer portal).

Comment: Sounds like the work-around to the iOS 8 caching issue then screws up effective app updates. Does the bundle-version make any difference?

Comment: @NicolasMiari the team identifier is not needed in the manifest.plist file. Pretty sure that comes in from the Provisioning Profile (App ID + Cert)

Comment: Yes; I meant that he should use the same provisioning profile (or another one created with the same prefix + bundle id).

Comment: I missed the "manifest" part of the question. My clarification was intended as generic app distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Only bundle ID (e.g. com.abc.xyz) needs to be remain same.

Comment: Why did you feel the need to repeat my answer?