# ipa installation failure through iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipa

I had an old ipa file which i used to install via iTunes in an iPad. But now i am not able to install the same ipa file . The image looks something like below which is beside music. What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: You need to add more detail like have you updated your iPad or Xcode? what are changed features between two occasion time?

Comment: ipad is not updated. it is the same version in which i was working earlier

Comment: old means..i installed it 2 days before

Comment: its an Enterprise ipa file

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733299/ios-8-cant-install-enterprise-app

Answer (score 0):

Seems like certificate used is expired. Try to revoke the certificate and build the IPA again. iOS checks the current device date with certificate expiration date. If certificate is expired, IPA wont install. Try to set device date with some older date.